# A double-D / A cap / A beanie / A bonnet

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, semantics, image-identification

[image]

1- I'm writing a story and one of my characters wears a bonnet. I searched the internet for some examples but then, I found other names like: A double-D / A cap / A beanie / A bonnet. Now I’m confused which one is more correct.

2- How do we call the three parts of the bonnet?

Comment: Just seeing your picture makes me interested in the story!

Comment: Well I'm working on it, but since I'm not a native speaker I sometimes have trouble describing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some searching with Google images ... "pom tassel beanie"

[image: tassel beanie]

[image: tassel beanie miami]  [LINK](https://www.nflshop.com/womens-miami-dolphins-47-brand-aqua-mckenzie-tassel-pom-knit-beanie/p-45294549201706+z-9180-2156863673)

It seems the two parts hanging down are "tassels" and the ball on top is a "pom".

Comment: Thank you so much, you're answer was most helpful.